# For loop for keys of map using streams

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

I want to check that is any of key of a map is contained in some other set and return true as soon as one match is found. The general way of doing it would be like

```
for each element in the set:
 for each key of the map:
  if current element of set == current key of map
   return true
```

I want to do this by making use of streams in Java. So I believe the way to convert the keys of map to a stream would be by

```
myMap.entries().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey)
```

but then run a for loop on each of that is what I am looking for.

Another way I thought was to something as below

```
myMap.keySet().forEach((k) -> set.contains(k));
```

but I want the outer loop to be of the set because the set has very less elements than the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write either

```
return myMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(set::contains);
```

or

```
return set.stream().anyMatch(myMap::containsKey);
```

The latter should be more efficient if the `Set` is smaller than the `Map`, since both `set::contains` and `myMap::containsKey` should take expected constant time (assuming a `HashMap`/`HashSet` implementation).

Comment: Too absentminded to have asked the complexity question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SonaliGupta actually I changed the part about the complexity. Streaming over the Set should be more efficient.

Comment: Noted above. for the second option will set.stream().anyMatch(myMap.entrySet()); be the same because I find it easier to read if it is the same for returning boolean.

Comment: @SonaliGupta you can't pass `myMap.entrySet()` to `anyMatch`, since it's not a Predicate. You'll have to pass `x -> myMap.entrySet().contains(x)`.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't compile. I wanted to understand that does it mean anyMatch within the entire entry set. But I think it means any element of the set matches any key of the map. Pretty clear. will further read in depth. Thanks for answering the questions.

Comment: Hello, If OP hadn't asked a streams based solution, because of comparison between two sets `Set.containsAll` should be the preferrable way to solve the problem ?

Comment: @dariosicily Hi. The OP didn't ask to find out if the Set contains **all** the keys of the map. They asked if the Set contains **any** key of the Map.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for your time, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

```java
Map<K, V> map = ...;
Set<K> keySet = ...;

boolean exists = map.keySet().stream().anyMatch(keySet::contains);
```

For more details see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).